# Cannot install UMBRACO CMS STARTER KITS - The installer can't connect to the repository

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, webmatrix, umbraco6, starter-kits

I am completely new to Umbraco & Webmatrix.
I am using **Windows 8 ,IIS version 8 & Webmatrix version 3**.
I tried installing **Umbraco v6.1.6**  but Step-5(Starter Kits) failed and gives me this error:

> **Oops...the installer can't connect to the repository** Starter Kits
>   could not be fetched from the repository as there was no connection -
>   which can occur if you are using a proxy server or firewall with
>   certain configurations, or if you are not currently connected to the
>   internet. Click Continue to complete the installation then navigate to
>   the Developer section of your Umbraco installation where you will find
>   the Starter Kits listed in the Packages tree.

I also tried to open it by clicking the 'Developer' button and then to the 'Packages' directory but still get the same error.

I also granted permission to the **IUSR & IIS_IUSR** to access **Windows/Temp** folder but still no luck.

In the web.config file i have also put this but still no luck :

> defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"

What should i do, guide me.
I don't know if its relevant or not but I want to just point out that my isp requires Windows VPN authentication to connect to the internet which i have set on my router to connect automatically, which it does and my internet is in working condition but **Umbraco could not load the repository of the starter kits**, I am stuck here.

Comment: Have you tried to download a startkit as a zip, and then install it manually from developer section?  [See starter kits here](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits?filter=free)

Comment: Windows/Temp does not seem like the location that Umbraco would be adding the files to. Did you mean {webroot}/App_Data?

Comment: as http://packages.umbraco.org/ is down right now which is causing the same error on my Umbraco install I will point to issue 5587 http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5587